# postgresql how we can see dead rows

Tags: postgresql

In case we disable auto vacuum
Is there any way I can see dead rows in my table.

I was using this function earlier but now seems it is not working:

```
SELECT * from page_header(get_raw_pages('emp',0));
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "dead rows" actually means to you?  I have never heard this term being used before.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the `pageinspect` extension.

`page_header` with give you, well, the page header, not the tuples.

Try

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pageinspect;

SELECT * FROM heap_page_item_attrs(get_raw_page('emp', 0), 'emp');
```

Comment: ok this is extension, But Module seems not in my machine can you let me how I can download this
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql12/extension/pageinspect.control": No such file or directory

Comment: You have to install the contrib package.